How to - create api to test simple http backend
I am new to WSO2 and evaluating for our environment.
I installed active and active 2 node WSO2 API M setup.
Now i have to test active/active cluster setup is working or not.
I have one httpd backend; which simple static page running in that HTTPD.
Now how to create API in WSO2 (Publisher & Developer portal) and test it?
Version installed is 4.2.0
Thanks for your support.

You could use HTTP Access logs in each node (AM_HOME/repository/logs/http_access_*) and view the access information. Once you access a portal (publisher/developer portal) there will be an entry in this logs. This way you could check whether requests are routing to nodes.
To check API invocations, you could enable wirelogs (see https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/configuring-logging/#enabling-the-gateway-wire-logs ) . When API is invoked, you could view which node is handling the request.

You can simply follow this documentation to create a new REST API using WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/design/create-api/create-rest-api/create-a-rest-api/.
